# Designing a menu, repeated message

Tags: c, algorithm, menu

I'm working on a console application which is supposed to have a little menu to choose from different options. I came up with two ideas, in one of which I used int to be a choice variable and it gets me into an infinite loop whenever I enter a character other than numeric. Another one though seems clearer to me but I can't understand why I get "Choose an option Not a digitChoose an option" message even if I choose a valid theoretically option Please let me know what's the problem with my code. I enclose the second example I mentioned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void F1()
{
    printf("Function 1\n");
}
void F2()
{
    printf("Function 2\n");
}
void F3()
{
    printf("Function 3\n");
}

int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("MAIN MENU\n"
         "1. Function 1\n"
         "2. Function 2\n"
         "3. Function 3\n"
         "4. Exit\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Choose an option ");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if(isdigit(c) == 0) printf("Not a digit");
        else 
        {
            if(c == '1') F1();
            else if(c == '2') F2();
            else if(c == '3') F3();
            else if(c == '4') break;
            else printf("Wrong option");
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush your input buffer to clear the `\n` character leftr behind by previous call of `scanf`. Place a space before `%c` in `scanf`

```
 scanf(" %c", &c);
```

or in general you flush input buffer by placing this snippet after each call of `scanf`:

```
int c
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: There is no need to check for '\n', which can fail under certain OSs. (DOS, Windows) The correct method is to only check for the EOF value.

Comment: @user3629249; It has been [never failed](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) since I have been programming.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to scanf() will real your typed character, and the second one will read a newline character.

You need to finish reading the line after your call to scanf():

```
int c2;
while((c2=getchar()) != '\n' && c2 !=EOF) {}
```